# Replicate openssl rsautl -verify as C/C++

Tags: c++, c, openssl, rsa, public-key

I am currently using the following command to sign a short test message:

```
      openssl pkeyutl -sign -in messageFile -inkey myPrivateKey.pem -out signedMessageFile
```

Note that I am signing the *message*; I am not using a digest.  I then use the following command to verify the text and recover the original message:

```
      openssl rsautl -verify -inkey myPulicKey.pem -pubin -out recoveredMessageFile.
```

The signing process is established and cannot be changed.
I want to replicate the verify-and-recover step by means of library calls.  I've tried using CryptPP to simplify the process (I have no expertise in cryptography), but it - apparently like many libraries - expects to sign a hash/digest and send the message in plain text.  That's not a viable solution for me.

Can anyone help me replicate the verify/recover command as C/C++ code, with or without an intermediate library?  Thanks!

Comment: Note that you're not signing a message, you're signing a digest. `pkeyutl -sign` takes in a digest as input. Notice how it can't sign anything longer than the key itself. [Here's](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5430/2015sp/notes/rsa_sign_vs_dec.php) a nice explanation of RSA signing vs. encryption.

Comment: The man page for pkeyutl says:
"In case of RSA, ECDSA and DSA signatures, this utility will not perform hashing on input data but rather use the data directly as input of signature algorithm. ... In general, with RSA the signed data can't be longer than the key modulus, .... otherwise it will be silently truncated to field size."
My messages are short (and of a defined length).  As I stated, I believe I'm signing the message itself.  And BTW, when I use verify and recover, I get the original message back.